# How to structure this Firebase data

Tags: firebase

I am working on an app that keeps track of bank transactions, and displays the data in a variety of ways. Each transaction object has only a few pieces of information (date, amount, type), but there will be hundreds of transactions.

At the moment I have 2 main nodes like this -

```
transactions
   user_id
      transaction_id
         date:
         amount:
         type:
categories
   user_id
      category_id
         transaction_id
            date:
            amount:
            type:
```

(The reason need access to the transaction data in the categories node as well is to perform analyses by category)

So I am storing each transaction object twice, and I wonder if this is the best way to do it. Because I also want to create another node that organises the transactions by month, so something like -

```
months
   user_id
      January
         transaction_id
            date:
            amount:
            type:
```

I have looked into how to structure data for two-way relationships, but the example [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) doesn't apply to this scenario because I need access to the full transaction data from each node

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to reference the node id, and add the node id to your second structure.

```
    Firebase *reference = [firebase1 childByAutoId];
    NSString* nodeId = reference.key;
```

This will allow you to retrieve the nodeId, and you can reference it in your second data structure.

Comment: Thank you, can you please send a link to the Firebase docs about using references? I can't seem to find anything

Comment: It's actually not a 'reference' in that sense - I believe he answer means to reference the string name of the node to get to the data. The childByAutoId creates a 'random' node name within the firebase1. The actual name, as a string, can be found by the key property (reference.key) and it will look something like -Jajski88y3438j. Duplication of data in Firebase is fine, but the duplication may be unnecessary in this case and could be avoided by leveraging the transaction_id in the categories and months node to get the data you need from the user_id node.

Comment: As a thought/question, couldn't the category_id be stored along with the date, amount and type data, then use a deep query to pull out the data from a single node? You would also be able to pull the data out by month if you time/date stamp it in the date property.

Comment: Hi @Jay , I think you may be right about just storing all the data in one node. It seems a better way to deal with this